# SSH connector in Mule 4

Tags: mule

I am attempting to SSH into a remote machine from a Mule flow. In Mule 4, I am unable to find an SSH connector component. 
Referring to the [SSH Connector](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/connectivity-dev/mule-in-a-shell-new-ssh-connector/) described on mule blog, I attempted creating an SSH connector as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:ssh="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssh"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssh http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssh/1.2.1/mule-ssh.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd"><ssh:config host="myhost" port="22" timeout="6000" callbackFlowName="callback" shellMode="true" /><http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="de27f2e8-04f3-439f-a422-327029a784b2" >
    <http:listener-connection host="localhost" port="8081" />
</http:listener-config>
<flow name="exampleFlow"> 
    <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="e3ba6e70-67cb-40bc-9017-9e036ba74c9a" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/"/>
    <ssh:send username="myuser" password="mypass" content="pwd" breakLine="true" /> 
</flow></mule>
```

This gives the following error:

```
    ERROR 2018-07-04 19:49:22,608 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer:
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    + Failed to deploy artifact 'ssh1', see below              +
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifact [ssh1]
    Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException: MuleRuntimeException: Can't resolve http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssh/1.2.1/mule-ssh.xsd, A dependency or plugin might be missing
    Caused by: org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException: MuleRuntimeException: Can't resolve http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssh/1.2.1/mule-ssh.xsd, A dependency or plugin might be missing
    Caused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error loading: ssh1.xml, Can't resolve http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssh/1.2.1/mule-ssh.xsd, A dependency or plugin might be missing
    Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Error loading: ssh1.xml, Can't resolve http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssh/1.2.1/mule-ssh.xsd, A dependency or plugin might be missing
    Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Can't resolve http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssh/1.2.1/mule-ssh.xsd, A dependency or plugin might be missing
```

System specifications

1. Anypoint 7.1.2
2. Mule Runtime 4.1.1 EE
3. JDK 1.8.0_172

Not sure if I am missing anything.

Can someone guide on how this can be done ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I tried to SSH into a remote machine using many routes, the one that worked was building a custom class in Java.
This Java class was built using the JSch library. A sample code can be seen at [LINK](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1418375956-Remote-execute-command-in-Java-example)

The flow for SSH is as follows:

1. Fetch host details and command from JSON payload.
2. Invoke Java class to SSH to a remote machine and execute a command.
3. Transform the output received to the desired format as send it back as response.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work. The Mule connector mentioned in the article is for an older version of Mule 3 and it is not compatible with Mule 4. It is also an open source connector, not maintained formally by MuleSoft.

Mule 4 provides an [SFTP connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/sftp-connector). If you need an SSH connector you will need to create it yourself from scratch or invoke custom Java code as in Nagesh answer. You can call the Java code using the [Java Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/java-module).